# Swift 3.0 - Core Data / Unexpectedly found nil

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I am not able to figure this one out by my self. I am retrieving some settings stored in Core Data, and print these setting to some UITextFields. This works fine in another VC in the same project but here I get "unexpexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional value".

I XCode I can see that the values are there? Why do I get this crash?
Please see attached screenshot.

[image]

This is the current code I am down to now. Still the same error message in XCode

```
func getSettingsFromCoreData() {
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "DeathMatchSettings")
    do{
        let results = try context.fetch(request)
        let managedObject = results as! [NSManagedObject]
        let getDMSettings = managedObject[0]

        guard let playerOne = getDMSettings.value(forKey: "playerOne") else {
            return
        }
        print(playerOne)
        txtPlayerOne.text = String(describing: playerOne)

    }catch{
        fatalError("Error in retreiving settings from CoreData")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Player1` can be ***nil***. You are trying to ***force downcast*** it to a value, but it is a fatal error in swift. Use an `if let` statement to test the value:

```
if let playerOne = getDMSSettings.value(forKey: "playerOne") as? String {
    print(playerOne)
    txtPlayerOne.text = playerOne
}
```

Read more about **type casting** in docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! But still I am not able to solve the issue. I changed according to your code above. I cannot understand why this value is nil. It should not be? And the value is printed fine into the console.

Comment: Please read some docs about Optional values, it is the feature number one in Swift. It doesn't automatically mean that your value is nil. It CAN be nil. That's why swift requires unwrapping an optional value to be able to operate with it for your purpose.

Comment: I have done a lot of reading, but still I am not able to figure this out. The strange part is that the exact same code is working just fine in another VC

Answer (score 0):

You can also use guard statement to unwrap your optional variable. It is better to use forced unwrapping only if you are confident that variable has non-optional value.

```
do {

   guard let playerOne = getDMSettings.value(forKey:"playerOne") else {
       return
   }

   print(playerOne)
   txtPlayerOne.text = playerOne
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Tried this also, still the same issue. the variable prints fine to console, but as soon as I try to use it on "txtPlayerOne" it faults with "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Can you update your code above? If you use guard statement and playerOne is holding an optional value, it should exit a function before printing its value.

Comment: Yes, the outcome is the same

Comment: If you did, could you see the value of playOne variable in a console screen?  Which line you program crashed? If you can share your project, I will look into it.

Comment: Thanks for your help woogii, strangely a restart of Xcode seems to have solved the problem all together! Now my original code works, and so does the way you suggested. Could be a beta 8.1 thing.